# Kubernetes UI select namespace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I created one **namespace** named *development* and two **replication controllers** (rc). The first rc belongs to the *default* namespace. The second rc belongs to the *development* namespace. I used the API ( `https://<ip>/api/v1/pods`) to confirm that are as many pods/rc as expected.

However the KUBE-UI displays only the resources (pods/rc/services/...) that belongs to the *default* namespace.

If possible, how could I display resources from other namespaces in KUBE-UI ?

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-ui/issues/35

Comment: I believe it's hardcoded the namespace - https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-ui/blob/80202f5ecfdf7cc059e8deb072088830eb43221d/master/shared/js/modules/services/k8sApiService.js#L5
 if the setNamespace method is never called, the default namespace is always taken, and the UI will only show the pods created within the namespace. The feature will come soon. (https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-ui/issues/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a 'reply' down to an 'answer'

From David Weston above:

I believe it's hardcoded the namespace - github.com/kubernetes/kube-ui/blob/… if the setNamespace method is never called, the default namespace is always taken, and the UI will only show the pods created within the namespace. The feature will come soon. (github.com/kubernetes/kube-ui/issues/5) –